# Groovy: Listing dynamic properties

Tags: mongodb, groovy

If I have an object persisted with GORM and the collection in Mongo that it's referencing changes, how can I list those properties? For instance (not my actual use case), I have a class called Toy and it has fields name and price, then somebody adds manufacturer to the db but not the code...

```
class Toy {
  String name
  Double price
}

class SomeController {
  def show() {
    def Toy t
    t = Toy.get(1)
    render t['manufacturer'] 
  }
}
```

t['manufacturer'] works fine.  The call to get loaded all the properties in the database regardless of the class's field definitions, but I (being very new to Groovy) don't know how to list those subscriptable properties to know if something has changed.

Answer (score 0):

Look at the properties field on the object

```
t.properties.each { prop, val ->
  println "Property: $prop $val"
}
```

But be aware that "metaClass" and "class" are always put there by groovy. A common idom in groovy is:

```
foo.properties.each { prop, val ->
    if(["metaClass","class"].find {it == prop}) return
    // else do something with the property or value
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I guess what you're really looking for are the dynamic properties set in the underlying mongo DB entity.

Do the following to get their names:

```
def nativePropertyNames = domainInstance.dbo.keySet()
```

If you only want the dynamic properties, this will do the trick:

```
def dynamicPropertyNames = domainInstance.dbo.keySet() - "_id" - domainInstance.properties.keySet()
```